# Possible to find internal format of texture in shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, shader

**Is it possible to find the internal format of a texture within the shader (glsl)?**

For example, if I have a texture with the format `GL_RG`, is it possible to recognize in the shader that the blue and alpha value are "constant" and can be ignored?

I know I can use a uniform to pass the texture type from c++ to the shaders. But is there an "intrinsic" way to find out from within the shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is anything that would give you this information directly.

Looking at the latest GLSL spec (4.50 at this time), I would expect a hypothetical function to get this information to be listed in section "8.9.1. Texture Query Functions" starting on page 158. But the only functions listed there are:

- `textureSize`: Get size of texture.
- `textureQueryLod`: Get the level of detail used for the given texture coordinates.
- `textureQueryLevels`: Get the number of mipmap levels in the texture.
- `textureSamples`: Get the number of samples for a multisampled texture.

So unless there is something completely different I missed, what you're looking for does not exist.